# Too many ordered factor levels for lm()

Tags: r, lm

I have a data frame with a `year` variable that spans over 100 years. The variable was originally an integer, but I thought it would be a good idea to convert it to an ordered factor.

```r
> myDf <- data.frame(year = factor(1900:1995, levels = 1900:1995, ordered = TRUE),
                   z = rnorm(96))
```

However, when I try to train the model, an error is produced.

```r
> myFit <- lm(z ~ year, data = myDf)

Error in ctrfn(levels(x), contrasts = contrasts) : 
orthogonal polynomials cannot be represented accurately enough for 95 degrees of freedom
```

After searching, all I could find was the following from the `contr.poly` source code.

```r
if (n > 95) 
  stop(gettextf("orthogonal polynomials cannot be represented accurately enough for %d degrees of freedom", 
                n - 1), domain = NA)
```

So I then tried the following:

```r
> myDf2 <- data.frame(year = factor(1900:1994, levels = 1900:1994, ordered = TRUE),
                    z = rnorm(95))
> myFit2 <- lm(z ~ year, data = myDf2)
```

It doesn't return an error.

Does the fact that the factor is ordered make a difference?

```r
> myDf3 <- data.frame(year = factor(1900:1995, levels = 1900:1995, ordered = FALSE),
                    z = rnorm(96))
> myFit3 <- lm(z ~ year, data = myDf3)
```

No errors are produced. Evidently, it is the ordering that causes this error.

I don't understand the significance of the cutoff at 95 degrees of freedom or how `contr.poly` is related to `lm`. Or is there a relation at all?  Why does the ordering matter?

Also, is ordering a factor with as many levels as I did unwise? My thought process was that I should convert `year` from integer to ordered factor because year doesn't "scale" in the same way that other variables in my dataset do, i.e., distance. Scale may not be the correct term, but I just mean that the year variable has contraints in the dataset whereas distance does not.

Comment: Also see `options("contrasts")` - the default method of generating contrasts for `ordered` factors in modelling is to use `contr.poly`

Comment: What is your purpose of performing the linear regression, to determine a trend or to model the previous years?  By setting year to a factor, the prediction for z will equal the mean of z for each year.  If the goal is to determine a trend then the year should be an integer.

Comment: @Dave2e The purpose of performing the linear regression is to predict `z`. There are 60 other variables in the original data, but I didn't include them in the sample.